# Integration table-view app with iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, tableview

I want to add iPad support to my iOS app.

My app is based on a tableView. 
So i have created an app for iPad, with split view, then copped 7 files from their to my iOS project. 
When i try to run the app i get it failed with error:

```
"ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
```

I'm not shier what does that mean, so, anybody, help me.
If you know an easier way to do that, i'm ready to try.

Comment: If the answer resolves the issue don't forget to accept it so others may notice the fix. If it doesn't work please give comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click Project Name icon that is blue then:

**Build Phases:**

Check the Copy Bundle Resources and look for any red items or duplicate files.

For a better idea of file  generating the error:

Look for a long path and at the end it should have a file name ending

Problem_Class_Name.o for architecture ...

Comment: Thanks, the app launched on iPad. But straight after that it shown me an error: `2013-12-11 19:43:26.865 iPoliglot[18957:70b] Unknown class MasterViewControlleriPad in Interface Builder file.
2013-12-11 19:43:26.870 iPoliglot[18957:70b] Unknown class DetailViewControlleriPad in Interface Builder file.
2013-12-11 19:43:26.893 iPoliglot[18957:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0xa394a80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key detailDescriptionLabel.'`